# How to remove mould (fungus) from clothes?

Tags: cleaning, clothing

I had left some wet clothes in a damp place for somever days due to my carelessness. The clothes have now developed black mould.

Washing clothes with detergent simply does not help.

What is the way out?

Comment: I had this problem with some cushion covers. I tried all the solutions I could find online - vinegar, detergent, bleach, normal laundry powder - but in the end I had to throw the worst-affected ones away :(

Answer (score 4):

Wash them again in the hottest water safe for the color of clothing. After putting the clothes in the washer, pour about two cups of white vinegar over them along with the detergent.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Two cups for that, I'd say. One cup is good for most things, but use more for mold.

Comment: 20th? I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: Sorry, that was a typing error.  I meant by a cup did you mean 250 ml?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Approximately. [1 US cup is 237 ml](https://www.google.com/search?q=1%20cup+to+ml).

Comment: A mixture of baking soda and vinegar is most effective to kill the fungus than either alone, since the chemical reaction produced by the mixture will effectively kill microorganisms. I don't know if can also remove 100% of the stains left by the mold, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following methods

1. Bleech
2. Borax
3. Vinegar
4. Baking Soda
5. Mold killing detergent

[More reference here](http://blackmold.awardspace.com/black-mold-clothes.html)

Comment: While this answer does provide possible solutions, it doesn't really offer enough detail as to how it should be applied and why it would work.